# Can't add an FBML application to Fan Page Tab

Tags: facebook, fbml

Last week we were able to install an FBML application to a Fan Page Tab. Now the Tab will not show up. See screenshot here: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/attachment.cgi?id=3075

FBML application: http://apps.facebook.com/alice-storefront/

Fan Page Test: http://www.facebook.com/pages/manage/#!/pages/Alice-Sandbox/150177181689663

The FBML application is installed but will not show up on the tab.

We have tried adding other applications to this page with no tabs being created. We have also tried creating new pages and adding the above application to the page with no luck.

I think we may be stuck in purgatory given the developer roadmap outlining that FBML applications will be deprecated "soon" but the switch to iframes for Fan Page tabs is murky (no documentation). See here:

*"We will begin supporting IFrames for Page tabs in the next few months. Developers building canvas applications should start using IFrames immediately. By the end of this year, we will no longer allow new FBML applications to be created, so all new canvas applications and Page tabs will have to be based on IFrames and our JavaScript SDK. We will, however, continue to support existing implementations of the older authentication mechanism as well as FBML on Page tabs and applications."*  - http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/402

How can we fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

This issue is a bug in Facebook. Which as of 10/25/2010 still exists.

It is outlined in their forum: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=238976#p238976

Essentially, with the Application Edit setiings the Canvas URL has 2 parts: 1. the default url and 2. an empty textbox below it. That textbox CANNOT BE EMPTY. Once I put a "?" in that textbox, which is the leader of the params string, the tab was finally displayed.

Detailed instructions as per the URL above:

1) Go to your APP Settings;

2) Go to the "Profile" "tab";

3) At "Tab URL" fill with:"?"     (without quotes);

4) Save your APP;

5) Go to your "Fan Page Settings";

6) Remove your APP;

7) Go back to your "APP Profile";

8) Click "Add to my Page";

9) Chose you page and click the "Add to Page" button;

10) Go to your "Fan Page" and now it will be avaliable on de "+" button on tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

FBML Tabs are still supported. Are you sure your FBML is working? When I go your FBML app the page is blank. I am wondering if there is just an error in your application that is causing this. Without code or more details I can't tell you any more about why your particular tab isn't working, but I can tell you that FBML tabs still can be created.